# How long can you store tissue on 4°C before B-cell extraction and culture?

Tags: cell-culture, tissue

We receive tissue regularly and extract B-cells for culturing, studying differentiation and survival with diffenet stimulation conditions. However, often the tissue arrives late afternoon and might be put in FCS at 4°C overnight before cell aextarction. I'm not sure however if such storage would impact the viability or functionality of B-cells later on during the culture.